# Who to contact when I don't know who's in the recruitment committee

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, hiring-process

Here's a timeline of my job interview process:

- From application to technical test: 28 days
- Informed that I'd passed the test: 5 days
- Time taken to set up first round of interviews: 19 days

I'm now waiting on them to set up the second (and final) round of interviews. It's been 20 days. I followed up with the product manager I talked with during the first round and she responded says that she isn't a part of the recruitment committee, that there were unexpected leaves and the schedule is still being sorted out (I received a response from her the day I email to check in last week).

In the meantime, the job posting (along with a couple of other positions) has gone back up on the site. I know this might just be routine and that they're hiring for many positions so scheduling may be an issue.

However, it's been a week since I had any contact from them and I'm not sure who is in the 'recruiting committee' to reach out to for a status update. I'm not sure how to proceed here- do I send and email to recruitment@company.com that I was initially contacted by or just write this opportunity off?

Answer (score 6):

No, you don't reach out to a recruitment committee.

The company should have, and probably has, a dedicated person or team to manage recruitment, who is almost certainly the person that initially reached out to you.

These people are often disjoint, either fully or partially, from any people that will be assessing you, who you call the recruitment committee.

I've been on these so-called recruitment committees before, and if I was contacted directly by the candidate, I would tell them to contact whomever contacted them about the job. I would offer them absolutely NO information about the recruitment process, no matter if the were successful, or not, or was ongoing. It's simply not my role, and I don't have a full picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, try to get in touch with the person who got in touch with you as the response of the job application in the first place. If that person is not available or it's an automated process, try asking the person you got in touch with next (the product manager).

To clarify, as they have already mentioned, they are not in the recruitment committee (whatever that means), it's likely that they are not responsible for getting interviews arranged / conducted, they are likely panel members for conducting the interview. Don't ask them about the update - ask whom you can reach out to to get an update on the process. They should be able to help you out.

Even after that if it's taking too long (yes, ~2 months is too long), don't bank upon this opportunity and keep looking elsewhere.

- If they get back, good - we'll move to next step.
- If they don't, good - you'll have other opportunities to explore.

Answer (score 1):

- Some companies just move slow, continue your job search and don't read into it too much.
- As others have said, a follow up email after a month is perfectly reasonable.
- Email the primary contact. Can CC whoever has been CC'ed previously, they will assume you just did "reply to all".
- It would be bad form if they "ghosted" at this stage, but there would be nothing to do about it. Don't assume either way